# "Making Predictions from 2D Data" code lab gives random results on each refresh

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've been following this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#0) but the result I get when testing the trained model looks way wrong, the code lab shows this chart

[image]

but when I run the code below, taken directly from the code lab my chart looks like this..

[image]

if I refresh again I get
[image]

and once more 
[image]

Why do the results vary so much in each page refresh?

I have tried delaying the testing but with no better results

```
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('Testing');
        testModel(model, data, tensorData);
       }, 6000);
```

I don't get why they look so different, my code below...

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as tfvis from "@tensorflow/tfjs-vis";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const testModel = (model: any, inputData: any, normalizationData: any) => {
      const {inputMax, inputMin, labelMin, labelMax} = normalizationData;  

      // Generate predictions for a uniform range of numbers between 0 and 1;
      // We un-normalize the data by doing the inverse of the min-max scaling 
      // that we did earlier.
      const [xs, preds] = tf.tidy(() => {

        const xs = tf.linspace(0, 1, 100);      
        const preds = model.predict(xs.reshape([100, 1]));      

        const unNormXs = xs
          .mul(inputMax.sub(inputMin))
          .add(inputMin);

        const unNormPreds = preds
          .mul(labelMax.sub(labelMin))
          .add(labelMin);

        // Un-normalize the data
        return [unNormXs.dataSync(), unNormPreds.dataSync()];
      });


      const predictedPoints = Array.from(xs).map((val, i) => {
        return {x: val, y: preds[i]}
      });

      const originalPoints = inputData.map((d:any) => ({
        x: d.horsepower, y: d.mpg,
      }));


      tfvis.render.scatterplot(
        {name: 'Model Predictions vs Original Data'}, 
        {values: [originalPoints, predictedPoints], series: ['original', 'predicted']}, 
        {
          xLabel: 'Horsepower',
          yLabel: 'MPG',
          height: 300
        }
      );
    }

    function convertToTensor(data:any) {
      // Wrapping these calculations in a tidy will dispose any 
      // intermediate tensors.

      return tf.tidy(() => {
        // Step 1. Shuffle the data    
        tf.util.shuffle(data);

        // Step 2. Convert data to Tensor
        const inputs = data.map((d:any) => d.horsepower)
        const labels = data.map((d:any) => d.mpg);

        const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
        const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

        //Step 3. Normalize the data to the range 0 - 1 using min-max scaling
        const inputMax = inputTensor.max();
        const inputMin = inputTensor.min();  
        const labelMax = labelTensor.max();
        const labelMin = labelTensor.min();

        const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
        const normalizedLabels = labelTensor.sub(labelMin).div(labelMax.sub(labelMin));

        return {
          inputs: normalizedInputs,
          labels: normalizedLabels,
          // Return the min/max bounds so we can use them later.
          inputMax,
          inputMin,
          labelMax,
          labelMin,
        }
      });  
    }
    const trainModel = async(model:any, inputs:any, labels:any) => {
      // Prepare the model for training.  
      model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
        loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
        metrics: ['mse'],
      });

      const batchSize = 32;
      const epochs = 50;

      return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
        batchSize,
        epochs,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
          { name: 'Training Performance' },
          ['loss', 'mse'], 
          { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
        )
      });
    }

    const createModel = () => {
      // Create a sequential model
      const model = tf.sequential(); 
      // Add a single input layer
      model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [1], units: 1, useBias: true}));
      // Add an output layer
      model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, useBias: true}));
      return model;
    }

    const getData = async () => {
      const carsDataReq = await fetch("https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/carsData.json");
      const carsData = await carsDataReq.json();
      const cleaned = carsData.map((car: any) => ({
          mpg: car.Miles_per_Gallon,
          horsepower: car.Horsepower
        }))
        .filter((car:any) => car.mpg != null && car.horsepower != null);
      return cleaned;
    }



    const run = async () => {
      const data = await getData();
      const values = data.map((d:any) => ({
        x: d.horsepower,
        y: d.mpg,
      }));

      tfvis.render.scatterplot(
        {name: 'Horsepower v MPG'},
        {values}, 
        {
          xLabel: 'Horsepower',
          yLabel: 'MPG',
          height: 300
        }
      );
      const model = createModel();  
      tfvis.show.modelSummary({name: 'Model Summary'}, model);

      const tensorData = convertToTensor(data);
      const {inputs, labels} = tensorData;

      // Train the model  
      await trainModel(model, inputs, labels);
      console.log('Done Training');
      testModel(model, data, tensorData);
    }
    run();
  });

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prediction values differs at each refresh because at each refresh there is a new training. The model weights are initialized with random values. During the training, the weights can either converge to optimum values or diverge. It depends on many parameters. Actually even the best model will not always converge at a fixed number of training epochs.

To always have the same value, the initial values of the weights can be set with fixed data. But again how to find this data that will lead to a best prediction ? That's not always easy to find those weights. A simple way to initialize a layer weights would be to use the `kernelInitializer` of the layer.

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [1], units: 1, useBias: true, kernelInitializer : 'zeros'}));
```

This new layer will have its weights initialized with 0. It is possible to use `ones` as well. Others initializers are possible. With fixed weights, the prediction will not change. But in practice weights are rarely initialized because of what is mentioned above unless one know for a certainty what possible values will lead to a good accuracy. What is done on the other hand is to track the model accuracy and create a checkpoint once there is a model with a satisfying accuracy.